# Usefulness of Child Trait?

Tags: scala, traits

The below function has general or specific errors.

```
scala> trait Error
defined trait Error

scala> case object General extends Error
defined object General

scala> trait FooError extends Error
defined trait FooError

scala> case object FooError42 extends FooError
defined object FooError42
```

Then, there's two functions:

```
scala> def f: Either[Error, Int] = Right(42)
f: Either[Error,Int]

scala> def h: Either[FooError, Int] = Right(55)
h: Either[FooError,Int]
```

Lastly, we can use a for-comprehension to chain them:

```
scala> for { 
     |  a <- f.right
     |  b <- g.right
     | } yield b
res3: scala.util.Either[Error,Int] = Left(FooError42)
```

In this case, the `Left`'s return type is `Error` since either an `Error` or `FooError` can occur for a `Left`. It's necessary to use `Error` since this type can express either a child of `Error` or `FooError` child.

Is it useful to further specialize `Error` into `FooError`, even though the `for-comprehension` returns a `Either[Error, Int]`.

In other words, is it useful to created a child `trait` of `Error` even though `FooError` isn't **directly** used?

Answer (score 1):

In your trivial example, the `FooError` seems redundant. In particular, 
it's not clear why a `General` is meaningfully different from the  various other objects/classes that may extend `FooError`. So I'd eliminate the latter from the design.

It makes more sense once you have some errors that have metadata (such as an error code) but some that do not, and you need to handle the two cases differently. You could then collect the former into a trait and declare the error code in the trait:

```
trait FooError extends Error {
  def rc: Int
}

object FooError42 extends FooError {
  val rc = 42
}
```

However, that's a lot of boilerplate that can be better dealt with by turning the trait into an abstract or case class, like so:

```
trait Error
object General extends Error
case class FooError (rc: Int) extends Error
object FooError42 extends FooError(42)
object NotFoundError extends FooError(404)
```

The use of a case class also then makes pattern-matching code a bit simpler:

```
def report(e: Error): String = e match {
  case FooError(rc) => "HTTP error " + rc
  case General      => "Complete and utter failure"
}
```